# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Writing's [first moderator election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Cyn]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5633032838971392/0).

Comment: Many thanks!  I'm looking forward to joining the team.

Answer (score 18):

Congratulations Cyn, and thank you Secespitus for also standing.  We had two strong candidates.

(Rumor has it that we'll have a full election for all the slots next year, so I hope the two of you *and several other active users* will throw your hats in then.)

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations, Cyn! Welcome to the team.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, Cyn! Thank you for taking this responsibility upon you. I wish you all the best in this and all of your other endeavors.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations Cyn!

Time to update the badge

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, Cyn! It's well-earned. Hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Cyn! I hope you have lots of fun here : D